# Do internal SOA services require authorisation?

Tags: soa

Imagine an architecture where a `public API` service exists as a gate between outside world and internal net of services. So the only way a query from a user can be processed is to go via that `public API`.

All the following services talk to each other within internal boundaries. All internal services are behind firewall and therefore can be accessed only either via `public API` or internal personnel.

Should the `public API` propagate Authorization session and then let the internal services to use it (they would need to verify the session on every request) or should the internal requests work without auth sessions as they are internal and not accessible by users?

Comment: Ideally this should be up to some chief of security to decide...!? More "firewalls" internally means more security in case of a breach. Whether this is something worth investing resources into is up to your company to decide.

Comment: Relevant if fine-grained access is desirable. Stateless nature of services should be considered to decide how to handle session info. In the end it would depend on what you expose and what's only available locally

Comment: @deceze it doesn't matter who decides what. it's about architectural best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Use auth internally as well.

You never know when (a) an internal service needs to be made external, or (b) someone inside your company (or an external hacker) figures out how to connect directly to the internal services and mucks everything up.

This isn't a requirement though, just good practice.

Comment: Internal services should never be made external. It's possible to put another layer of abstraction with an API wrapper. In regards to the (b) if a hacker figures out how to connect to the internal services, I am sure he will also be able to spoof auth services.

Comment: @ArtursVancans - For (a) - this can heavily depend on your definition of internal/external: used only by you? your team? your company? Having some form of auth will at least help prevent accidents from "internal" users accessing parts they shouldn't.  For (b) - this is possible but not necessarily the case in a well designed system.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a requirement, as Chris pointed out - it is good to have it, but as with all security-related matters, you must be careful to not overdo it. It may prove to be kind of redundant to your external security if you don't care for internal personnel accessing services.

You can try to propagate the Authentication/Authorization to the deepest level in the chain of communication, but keep in mind that this is not very realistic, because it implies that all your systems (be it legacy or 3rd party, or some COTS) have some auth mechanisms built-in. In the end you'll probably have some 3rd party system that uses a specific API that doesn't understand your external authorization at all. It might use its own form of auth. At this point you'll have to switch security contexts in order to keep security *end-to-end*.

Also, this will surely be:

- some overhead performance-wise,
- when someone develops a new consumer for a particular service will have to conform to auth rules.
- live debbuging will be a bit harder, because you will need to impersonate an external user in order to debug an internal service.

Now, all the above **is not to say that no security is better**, just have the cons in mind as well. In my experience, often a restriction by IP is used internally and that is about enough in terms of security.

Also keep in mind that you'll always have some employees that must have access to everything, so you cannot have 100% security either way.

So, consider the pros Chris gave, consider the cons I did, and decide what is the best in your specific case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In SOA there would be an auth service that would verify auth tokens therefore services would not need to know the auth implementation. The only thing they would have to do is to call auth service to confirm token legitimacy.

Comment: @ArtursVancans In this case yes, but this is still overhead even if not that huge (putting the said auth service in place also requires effort). And this holds true only for providers, consumers will have to pass this token. Let's not forget that the post mentions federated service layer, but this is far from a fully functional SOA. The question of SOA maturity in this particular case remains open to interpretation since you never mentioned it.